# How to preserve new lines in CKEditor 5?

Tags: ckeditor5

I am using Angular 2+ with CKEditor 5.

When I use the string: `"foo\r\nbar"`, the text inside the editor is not applying the new lines. Using a CSS rule: `white-space: pre-line;` on the text in other elements on the page works, but not in CKEditor. How can I preserve the new lines in CKEditor 5?

Here is my component:

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
@Component({
      selector: 'test',
      templateUrl: './test.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent {
      public editor = ClassicEditor;
      testString = "foo\r\nbar";
      constructor(){}
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<ckeditor [editor]="editor" [(ngModel)]="testString"></ckeditor>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace "\r\n" with `"<br />"` in the string using javascript, before you give it to ckeditor.

Comment: And when you retrieve it, do I need to parse all <br> with \r\n again?

Comment: Yes, if you want plain text from ckedtior instead of html. But what about all the other html ckeditor might insert, for things such as bold text, paragraphs and so on. Do you really want to edit plain text without any html?